# Python - How to use a for loop to write data to a cell, then move to the next row

Tags: python, excel

I have what feels like a problem with a relatively simple solution, but to this point it escapes my research. I'm attempting to write items from a tuple to four consecutive rows using a for loop, but I can't seem to figure it out. I suspect that it can be done with the iter_rows module in the openpyxl package, but I haven't been able to properly apply it within the loop. The following piece of code results in the generation of an .xlsx file with the last item from the tuple assigned to cell 'A2':

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

nfc_east = ('DAL', 'WAS', 'PHI', 'NYG')

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.active

row_cell = 2

for i in nfc_east:

    column_cell = 'A'
    ws.cell(row = row_cell, column = column_cell).value = str(i)
    row_cell = row_cell + 1

wb.save("row_creation_loop.xlsx")
```

All suggestions and (constructive) criticism welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is write the cells from the tuple, you can directly do that with a syntax like - `ws['A1'] = <something>` this would write the value into the cell `A1` .

Example -

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
nfc_east = ('DAL', 'WAS', 'PHI', 'NYG')
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for row, i in enumerate(nfc_east):
    column_cell = 'A'
    ws[column_cell+str(row+2)] = str(i)

wb.save("row_creation_loop.xlsx")
```

When you are using the syntax - `ws.cell(row = row_cell, column = column_cell).value` , the column_cell has to be integer, not a string , so for `A` column, you have to give the value for `column` argument as `1` (for `B` it would be `2`) , etc.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will attempt this when I get home from work in a few hours. Will update when I do.

Comment: It worked! Thank you, I will brush up on my enumerate documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't run for me (`Invalid column index A`). Which version of pyxl are you using? AFAIK pyxl uses integer indexes. The following code produces the output you're after (I think).

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

nfc_east = ('DAL', 'WAS', 'PHI', 'NYG')
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

start_row = 2
start_column = 1

for team in nfc_east:
    ws.cell(row=start_row, column=start_column).value = team
    start_row += 1

wb.save("row_creation_loop.xlsx")

#  Prints...
#
#   |  A  |
# 1 |     |
# 2 | DAL |
# 3 | WAS |
# 4 | PHI |
# 5 | NYG |
```

Comment: I'm almost positive that I'm using the current version of openpyxl, but I will clarify when I get home from work later. Thank you!